# nonlinear ODE's involving heaviside step functions: The bouncy ball as an example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, nonlinear-dynamics

The dynamical equation for a ball bouncing on a plate (located at $x=0$) can be represented as
$$ \ddot{x}(t) = -g - (k_1 x + k_2 \dot{x})H(-x), $$
where $H(x)$ is a heaviside step function and the collisions between the ball and the plate are represented with a spring-dashpot model. I would like to solve this equation for $x(0) = x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0) = v_0$. One can solve this by calculating the velocity and time of the first collision, evaluating the Newtonian dynamics during the collision, then repeating this process iteratively through collisions. Obviously the resulting piecewise trajectory would be something like the following:

[image]

This approach is somewhat unsatisfactory because I would ideally like to solve for the trajectory $x(t)$ at any arbitrary time, and this approach only yields a piecewise solution. A priori I do not know how many collisions have occurred up to a given time at which $x(t)$ is desired, so I would need to iterate an arbitrary number of times to find a solution.

I wonder if there are specialized approaches to solve such ordinary differential equations analytically. The above equation is nonlinear and defined only in the sense of a distribution (since $H(x)$ is not exactly a function). Clearly the solution exhibits discontinuities. Are there any approaches I might read about to better understand such equations or solve such equations with more powerful tools than piecewise integration?

Comment: Have you solved the Newtonian dynamics during the collision?

Comment: Provided $k_1$ is large enough to neglect $g$, it's just a damped harmonic oscillator during collision until $x$ hits $0$ again.

Comment: Wouldn't it take infinitely many bounces to stop in an idealized model such as this?

Comment: yes @Eli. That's not an issue as far as I'm concerned. such approaches are regularly used to describe granular materials for example https://www.icevirtuallibrary.com/doi/10.1680/geot.1979.29.1.47

Comment: However I tried to solve this analytically without doing so iteratively, I ended up comparing it to my iterative solution to see if it was correct. Perhaps that's because the iterative solution is the correct analytical solution? The only 'single' function I could think of is to have an infinite sum of coefficients with Heaviside functions to pick out the correct coefficient for the corresponding bounce, but this is just the iterative process disguised. I'd compare the feeling of the iterative solution not feeling like the true solution to how I feel about series solutions.

Comment: The plot and differential equation are not really consistent. The particle spends a non-negligible time in the region x<0. So I think you should decide what you're actually asking for: a model that reproduces the plot with instantaneous collisions, or solutions for the differential equation that you wrote.

Comment: @Sal the contact time can be made arbitrarily short by adjusting $k_1$ and $k_2$. Such models are commonplace in contact dynamics. The plot and model are completely consistent. That said an event driven approach which sends $v \rightarrow -\epsilon v$ instantaneously on collision may be easier.

Comment: @kevinkayaks That is true, for any given bounce. But compare the time spent below the axis in one bounce: $T_-=\pi/\sqrt{k_1-k_2^2/4}$ (constant) to the time spent above the axis $T_+=2v_0/g$ where $v_0$ is the velocity at the beginning of that bounce. Since $v_0 \to 0$ for large $t$, there will always be a time beyond which $T_-$ is not negligible compared to $T_+$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Follows a self explanatory MATHEMATICA script to cope with simulations.

```
parms = {g -> 9.81, k1 -> 1, k2 -> 0.1, x0 -> 10, mu -> 0.95}
tmax = 10;
ode = Join[ {x''[t] == -g - k1 x[t] - k2 x'[t], x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 0}, {WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, x'[t] -> -mu x'[t]]}] /. parms
solx = NDSolve[ode, x, {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. solx], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]